# Java Hibernate extended class doesn't create join table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have following issues with the main class User being created in the database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BookEntity> books = new HashSet<>();

}
```

and also the users_books table is created. Now I have a new class StudentEntity that extends UserEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class StudentEntity extends UserEntity {
    private String studentId;

    //...
}
```

Hibernate also creates now students table in the database but students_books table is not created. So now trying to persist StudentEntity in the database causes Error:
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...

Any ideas what can be done so the students_books table is also created?